# Rails 3 Using Locales for Error Messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling

So I have a column name in my Order table named `b_name` . However, when I get the error message, it says `B name can't be blank`. My column b_name is an abbreviation for Business Name. Is it possible to change my column `b_name` to be referenced as Business Name using locales. If so, could you please provide a tutorial or show me an example. I have tried a couple of ways such as this:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      model_name:          "Order"
    attributes:
      model_name:
        b_name:            "Business Name"
```

and that did not change the error message. I even tried this:

```
HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES = {
  :lname => ""
}
def self.human_attribute_name(attr)
  HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES[attr.to_sym] || super
end
```

but got an error message saying wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) on line #3

```
1: <% if object.errors.any? %>
2:   <div id="error_explanation">
**3**:     <h2><%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %> 
4:         prohibited this <%= object.class.to_s.underscore.humanize.downcase %> 
5:         from being saved:</h2>
6:     <p>There were problems with the following fields:</p>
```

Any suggesetions to help me accomplish my task?

Thanks in advance!